# Changing timestamp on ActiveMQ Artemis messages

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are sending messages to ActiveMQ Artemis 2.11.0 via the JMS connector in Boomi using the core JMS client library. However, when looking at the messages on the queue via the ActiveMQ management console the timestamp of messages in queues is different from current time and date. The messages in the queue are from today but you can see it has a date in September of last year:

[image: wrong timestamps]

Any idea how to fix that configuration?

Comment: Hi Justin We are using Artemis 2.11.0. I am sending messages via JMS connector in Boomi. I am looking at messages on the queue via Active MQ management console.

Comment: I have tried to paste a screenshot, but couldnt figure out how. This is my first post on Stack overflow so still figuring it out. I will get back to you on the information shortly

Comment: Hello Justin, we are using core JMS to connect to Artemis. Here are the jars being used by Boomi

Comment: Hello Justin, we are using core JMS to connect to Artemis. Here is the link to screenshot. The messages in the queue are from today but you can see it has a date in Sep of last year. "https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-K5OJYXRqRiFSg5t50_D7j5geb3XOnA/view?usp=sharing"

Comment: ok, i will try to upgrade and see if that works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Justin - Upgrading the Artemis to 2.17 fixed the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move to the [latest release of ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) (2.17.0 at this point). The 2.11.0 release is over a year old at this point. There's been a handful of releases since then with hundreds of bug fixes.